# Color problem on the bottom right corner?

Tags: faces

I am using terminal `emacs`. Please see the screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

There is a dark area which is not matching with the background in the bottom right corner of the screen. What is the `face` for that?

How do you deal with issues like this? Is there an `emacs` wireframe which can tell which what these UI components are?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this part was actually Terminal Emulator's background color. Matching it with `emacs` worked fixed the issue. If anyone has a good way to troubleshoot these type of issues, please do share.